# string.indexof(")") not working

Tags: java, string

When i run following code its output is

```
lcp-   -1  ncp-   -1
```

I required the following output:

```
lcp-   8  ncp-   8
```

Code:

```
public static void main(String str[]) {
    String fun="M(a,b,c);"; 
    String inputset;
    char m,op;
    fun=fun.substring(0, fun.length()-2);
    //Vector<String> input=new Vector<String>();
    int indx=0;
    String cp;
    cp = ")";
    if(fun.charAt(0)=='M' &&  fun.charAt(1)=='('){
        int lcp=fun.lastIndexOf(cp);
        int ncp=fun.indexOf(cp);
        System.out.println("lcp-   "+lcp+"  ncp-   "+ncp);
    }
}
```

When I run the code it print -1, -1 for both lcp and nap. How can I fix it?

Comment: Note that in Java, the definition of `s.substring(a,b)` is that it returns the string up to **but not including** the character at `s.getChar(b)`.  That's why the `)` got removed from `fun`.

Answer (score 3):

`fun=fun.substring(0, fun.length()-2);` will make `fun` equal to `M(a,b,c`. So, you will never have `)` in the String. To remove `;` from `fun`, use `fun=fun.substring(0, fun.length()-1);` instead.

Comment: still you will not get output as lcp- 8 ncp- 8, Because ')' is at 7th position.

Comment: @vvp - Ya, that's because `")"` is at index 7 :P. But I guess the OP got that

Answer (score 0):

Still you can get answer : `lcp-   7  ncp-   7`

You need to add 1 before printing in b

```
System.out.println("lcp-   "+ (lcp+1) +"  ncp-   "+(ncp+1));
```